# How to change font / increase font size of Radio button on Inno Setup CreateInputOptionPage

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I have added a new page - `CreateInputOptionPage`
added a few options.

```pascal
wpWizardPage.Add('Option A');
wpWizardPage.Add('Option B');
wpWizardPage.Add('Option C');
```

I want to increase the font size of the radio button list.

I appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 5):

Use

```pascal
wpWizardPage.CheckListBox.Font.Size := 123;
```

See https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TNewCheckListBox

Comment: Thank you, Slappy, You are an Inno Setup Expert. :-)

Comment: @RajendraDewani thanks, please mark the answer as solution to help other SO users.